# Pass Class as parameter

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to pass a Class reference and instantiate it in a function. This doesn't work:

```
function foo(myClassRef:Class):Void {
    var myVar = new myClassRef();
}
foo(MyClass);
```

It gives `Unexpected (`.

Is this possible in Haxe 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Class](http://api.haxe.org/Class.html) has a [Type Parameter](http://haxe.org/ref/type_params), so if you're going to accept a class as an argument, you need to specify a type parameter.

Accept any class:

```
function foo(myClassRef:Class<Dynamic>):Void {
    var myVar = Type.createInstance( myClassRef, [constructorArg1, constructorArg2....] );
    trace( Type.typeof(myVar) );
}
```

Accept only "sys.db.Object" class or sub classes:

```
function foo(myClassRef:Class<sys.db.Object>):Void {
    var myVar = Type.createInstance( myClassRef, [] );
    trace( Type.typeof(myVar) );
}
```

Haxe 3 also allows [generic functions](http://haxe.org/manual/haxe3/features#generic-functions):

```
@:generic function foo<T:Dynamic>(t:Class<T>) {
    var myVar = new T();
    trace( Type.typeof(myVar) );
}
```

Here you declare the function to be generic, which means that for each different type parameter, a different version of the function will be compiled.  You accept Class, where T is the type parameter - in this case, dynamic, so it will work with any class.  Finally, using generic functions let's you write `new T()`, which may seem a more natural syntax, and there may be performance benefits on some platforms.

Comment: I just want to add, that with Dead Code Elimination set to full (-dce full), the constructor of the class would be eliminated if it's not used anywhere else.
To fix this, we should prepend the constructor signature with @:keep metadata, [like this](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1891).

Comment: I may be wrong, but according to the documentation (haxe 3.2.0) it's `Type.createInstance( myClassRef, [args]);` That is, no `constructor` in the params.

Comment: That was just me writing trying to write a sentence.  I could have also written `Type.createInstance(myClassRef, [arg1,arg2,arg3])`.  Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 4):

It is possible in Haxe3 and Haxe2

```
function foo<T>(myClassRef:T):Void {
var myVar = new T();
```

}

Note: Haxe3 class (where foo is implemented) must be @:generic if you want new T() to work.

Haxe2 is another story:

```
function foo<T>(myClassRef:Class<T>):Void {
var myVar = Type.createEmptyInstance(Type.getClass(myClassRef));
```

}